# What to do, if I need non generic class use generic inside, but don't want pass down type arguments

Tags: design, object-oriented, refactoring

Let's assume we have something like that:

```
class Page{
    Header header;
    Body body;
    Footer<TFooterModel> footer;  //TFooterModel is a type of content (subcontrol in some sense) that loaded inside footer.

    public Page(Header h, Body b, Footer<TFooterModel> f){...} //Let's assume that we setting part in constructor or using Builder pattern. 

}
```

So, `Footer` is generic one. However, it will be logically wrong, to make `Page` also generic and use `Page<TFooterModel>`, just because I don't really use `TFooterModel` anywhere inside, except specifying `Footer's` type. Converting `Footer` to inheritance chain also seem wrong, since it's just a container for some content and there is no sense in inheritance, since children will be identical. This is looks like design issue for me, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

So, what is a proper way to handler those scenario, which really great developers use?

---

Footer it's just a container, which load some content using `loadContent(BaseContent content)`, but it has an event. `onContentLoaded(OnContentLoadedHandler<ContentImpl> handler)`, so just single difference between children will be a type of `OnContentLoadedHandler` used, that's why I think that inheritance is something to much.

---

There was some options proposed.

1. Create non-generic `Footer`, inherit generic footer from
   non-generic, and use non-generic inside Page
2. Pass OnContentLoadedHandler in `Footer's` constructor and avoid
   generic (however my personal opinion, it's could have some pitfalls, due to type resolving when calling handler (if it's lambda for example, or if it's `dynamic`, but i'm not fully sure.))
3. Add interface and use it instead (probably logically similar to 1.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why there's a problem with just using `Footer<TFooterModel>` as you show above...?  What exactly is the problem that you need to "fix"?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: The part of the question which is **extremely** unclear is: where/when shall the concrete type for the type variable `TFooterModel` be provided (I am pretty sure you meant it to be a type variable, otherwise there would not be any problem.)

Comment: Let's assume they added in constructor

Comment: Broken english.

Comment: It's open for editing. You always could fix grammar and spelling if you don't like it, instead of point to shortcomings. it's always better to show on personal example.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Page {
    Header header;
    Body body;
    Footer<TFooterModel> footer;
}
```

If `TFooterModel` is a *concrete type* (class or interface in your codebase, and all of its parameters instantiated to concrete types) this is fine; there is no need to define a separate class that inherits from it.

If `TFooterModel` is instead a *type variable* (not a concrete type), then this code is ill-typed; `Page` would need to have that type variable as its parameter as well (`Page<TFooterModel>`).  There's no getting around this, because all actual instantiated objects of a generic type must be instantiated with some choice of concrete type for all of their type parameters.

So *something* has to instantiate `Footer`'s type parameter to a concrete type.  If `Page` is not going "pass up" a type parameter for this, then it might as well be `Page` itself that instantiates `Footer`'s parameter.  That way:

- If `TFooterModel` is a concrete type, then the code example is already the best solution.
- If `TFooterModel` is a type variable, then all that `Page` needs to do is change it to a concrete type.

The other idea that has been presented is that, instead of `Page` instantiating `Footer`'s parameter to a concrete type, have some third class that extends from `Footer` just to do this instantiation.  This is just pointless, and defeats the purpose of using generics in the first place—that we can reuse `Footer` with various instantiations of its parameters without having to write new classes or perform unsafe runtime casts.  The only reason to subclass from `Footer` would be to provide some additional functionality that's not already generically present in the superclass.

Comment: OP specifically requested a solution that doesn't require a generic argument on `Page`. Good point about `TFooterModel` possibly being a  concrete type, but in this case, I believe the OP was describing a situation where `TFooterModel` is a generic type parameter (and used C# naming conventions for type parameters). If the OP hadn't specifically requested a non-generic `Page` solution, I would've agreed with this answer.

Comment: @wablab: I've edited my answer to make it clearer, but I fully stand by it otherwise. Keep in mind that OP didn't even specify whether `TFooterModel` is a concrete type or a type variable—we can't even tell whether the example code is well-typed or not!

Comment: TFooterModel is a type of content (subcontrol in some sense) that loaded inside footer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class named `Footer` (not generic).  Change your `Page.footer` to this type:

```
class Page {
  Header header;
  Body body;
  Footer footer; // note we changed the type of this field
}
```

Derive another class named `Footer<TFooterModel>` from your base `Footer` class:

```
public class Footer<TFooterModel> : Footer {
  ...
}
```

Instantiate your footer however you normally do, and assign it to `Page.footer`.

---

To clear up some confusion about this answer:

1. Why not make `Page` generic (i.e. `Page<TFooterModel>`)? In short: because the OP asked for a solution that didn't require a generic argument on the `Page` class.
2. Why is this answer better than option 3 in the OP's list? It's not necessarily better. It's just my preference to use a class here since `body` and `header` are classes and are basically the same thing as `footer` (containers for page data).
3. Why is this answer better than option 2 in the OP's list? It's not necessarily better. Option 2 would probably work but seemed less straightforward than this option (after all, something has to host those generic callbacks you'd be passing in, so you're probably still going to end up with a `Something<TFooterModel>`.

Comment: Why I think that make Page generic - is a bad idea. In M.Fowler's book or in Code Complete (don't remember for sure) was mention, that even if you pass variable in class or method, and don't use it somewhere in class/method, instead of just passing down to other class/method - this is a "smell" which indicate some design problem. For my point of view, things goes even worse if we talk about generic type. This will be absolutely confusing for class client - why he need to make this class typed, and especially which type he need to use, since this type don't really use anywhere in class code.